# Connecting to MSSQL Server - QGIS 3.28 & Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu, odbc

I've been using QGIS + Ubuntu for some time now, great combination.
Last week I've updated from Ubuntu 22.04 to Ubuntu 22.10 and subsequently to Ubuntu 23.04. During this upgrade the system has uninstalled QGIS (I was using 3.30) and all the settings stored. This seems to be not important, as the first thing that I've done is installing QGIS again.

One of the things that have made me happy lately was that I've been able to connect from QGIS to my MSSQL Server flawlessly. Sadly with this late update this is not the case.

I have installed (and working ok) the latest MSSQL driver from Microsoft:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep msodbcsql
rc  msodbcsql17                                       17.5.2.1-1                                amd64        ODBC Driver for Microsoft(R) SQL Server(R)
ii  msodbcsql18                                       18.0.1.1-1                                amd64        ODBC Driver for Microsoft(R) SQL Server(R)
```

I have properly configured the odbc.ini file with the ODBC that I need.
I can connect using the isql -v    command:

```
$ isql -v DB_CHARGE user password
+---------------------------------------+
| Connected!                            |
|                                       |
| sql-statement                         |
| help [tablename]                      |
| quit                                  |
|                                       |
+---------------------------------------+
SQL>
```

However, when I try to connect from QGIS I get the following:

[image]

The same message "Driver not loaded" appears if I click List Databases or Test Connection. Also, it does not make any difference if I set up the Server or if I click - unclick any of the other options.

Edit:

This is the output in syslog:

```
$ sudo tail -n 20 /var/log/syslog    
2023-04-24T13:39:09.952237-03:00 leandro-ThinkPad-P1-Gen-2 org.qgis.qgis.desktop[35398]: Warning: QSqlDatabase: QODBC driver not loaded
2023-04-24T13:39:09.952354-03:00 leandro-ThinkPad-P1-Gen-2 org.qgis.qgis.desktop[35398]: Warning: QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE
```

Comment: you need the drivers https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=debian18-install%2Cdebian17-install%2Cdebian8-install%2Credhat7-13-install%2Crhel7-offline

Comment: I do have the drivers installed - I've tryied removing and reinstalling but doesn't works.
I'm using dbveaver that runs ok, and also connecting from command line to the DB works fine as well.

Comment: I have this to and the drivers work for ogr2ogr and ogrinfo. Not sure what they are looking for here.